# How to implement this algorithm to counting inversions in different array sizes?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

```
NUMSEXP = 10
for n in 5000, 10000, 15000 ... 50000
totalTime = 0;
    for i in 1 ... NUMSEXP
        A <- new array of n random numbers from 1 to 10*n 
        startTime <- get currentTime
        inversions <- countInversions and Sort
        endTime <- end time
        totalTime <- totalTime + (endTime + startTime)
    print n, totalTime/NUMSEXP
```

I'm trying to implement the algorithm above using this code but i'm having trouble creating the for loop that changes the array size from 5000 to 10000 until 50000.
I already have the part that makes the algorithm runs 10 times and counts the inversion with the timers. This is the code i have, it keeps running an infinite loop.

```
for(int n = 0; n < 50000; n =+ 5000) {
                
                    //primer inicializador de array con numeros random
                    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
                        arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (10 * arrSize));
                    }
                    //para verificar si el algoritmo corre 10 veces
                    int count = 1;
                    //corre el algoritmo 10 veces
                    for(int j = 0; j < NUMSEXP; j++) {
                        //inicializa array con numeros random
                        for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
                            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (10 * arrSize));
                        }
                        
                        long srtTime = System.nanoTime();
                        //corre algoritmo
                        int inversionCount = countInversionAndSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
                                    
                        //termina de contar en nano segundos cuanto se tarda en correr el algoritmo
                        long ndTime = System.nanoTime();
                                    
                        //imprime cuantas veces conto el algoritmo
                        System.out.println(count++ + " Inversion Count: " + inversionCount);
                                    
                        //imprime cuanto tiempo se tardo el algoritmo en completar
                        System.out.println("Elapsed Time in Nano seconds: "+ (ndTime-srtTime) + "\n \n");

                }   
            }
```

Comment: Or is it that the algorithm takes too long to finish because of the array sizes?

Comment: `n =+ 5000` at the top of  your main loop - that doesn't look right.

Comment: Yes, it should be `n += 5000` or `n = n+5000`. What you are doing is `n = (+5000)`, i.e. you are assigning the value 5000 to `n` after each iteration.

Comment: `for(int n = 5000; n <= 50000; n =+ 5000) {  arrsize = n;...`